# Problem loading a URL in WKWebView that works fine on SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm trying to load the following url inside a `WKWebView`: `https://sia.unal.edu.co/ServiciosApp/facespublico/public/servicioPublico.jsf?taskflowId=task-flow-AC_CatalogoAsignaturas` but it is not working as expected.

When loading it on a `SFSafariViewController` it works fine, but on the `WKWebView` it is redirected to another page.

I've managed to discover that at some point, there is a hidden redirect to something like `https://sia.unal.edu.co/ServiciosApp/facespublico/public/servicioPublico.jsf;PortalJSESSION=e6xDmtoAdOmF8ust2Ar3fFL4gK9duLOgm2jEkRWIov3MUM_nT_-X!-1477800785?taskflowId=task-flow-AC_CatalogoAsignaturas`.

Therefore, I started trying to load these 'new urls' into the `WKWebView`, but the result was the same (redirected to another page).

I also disabled redirects, and the `WKWebView` stays blank (and no error is sent on the delegate). I've also tried to change the cookies policy, adding javascript enabled, but the behaviour stays the same.

I would appreciate some help with this issue. As the url is public access, you can replicate the difference in behavior between the `WKWebView` and the `SFSafariViewController`.

I would also appreciate some information regarding

```
Why is the behaviour of this specific url so different between both options?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is caused by the User-Agent header being different when loading via a WKWebView vs SFSafariViewController.  The website you are loading must be using the User-Agent header to determine where to redirect.

By setting the `customUserAgent` property on your WKWebView to the default iOS Safari User-Agent the same page will be directed to in your WKWebView as when using SFSafariViewController:

```
webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

Comment: Wow! Thank your very much. I wasted soooo much time in this. You're the best!
The string should be updated with new Safari versions, right?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine you'd need to update the Safari version, it will probably work with any User-Agent that an actual web browser would use.

Comment: Hi ,same problem we are also facing with my app,the prod url is opening in SFSafariViewController but not in Wkwebview(from ios 16.1 onwards),any help on this issue really appraicate

Comment: that worked for me! the latest user agents: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/safari